# MVC Add reference to views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my views I need to add a reference to another class/ resource files.

I add to each view

```
@using Demo.Extensions;
```

and to add resource reference to views I do this:

```
@using Resources;
```

This does work, just annoying to add to each view. Is it possible to add reference once somewhere, web.config i think. so I dont need to worry about adding to each views

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `/Views/Web.config` (not root) you can include your namespace so that it will be included in all of your views.

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="PATH_TO_YOUR_NAMSPACE" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: I don't have Web.config (dot net core 1.2)